# TKinter Python GUI alignment

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following code for my GUI:

```
root = Tk()
draft = Frame(root)
draft.grid()
root.title("test")
var = StringVar()
emailLabel = Label(draft, text="E-Mail:")
emailLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

email = Entry(draft, justify=LEFT)
email.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
email.insert(0, "E-Mail")

passLabel = Label(draft, text="Pass:")
passLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

password = Entry(draft, justify=LEFT, show="*")
password.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
password.insert(0, "Password")

start = Button(draft, text = "Start")
start.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

stop = Button(draft, text = "Stop")
stop.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

status = Text(draft)
status.grid(row = 3)
status.insert(INSERT, "TESTING")
```

However, it's not lining up the way I want it. I want the label and textboxes aligned to the left not the right, and the status text box to take up the entire size of the bottom (It's more or less a log).

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `Text` widget span over multiple columns, use the `columnspan` argument:

```
status.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
```

Additionally, you can use the `sticky` parameter in the `grid` method to make the widgets occupy as many space as possible. Use this in every `grid` call:

```
widget.grid(..., sticky=N+W+E+S)
```

If you want the labels to be smaller, you have to rethink your layout a bit.

(Little note: it's not suggested to import `*` from tkinter. `import tkinter as tk` is preferred.)

Comment: I agree about not liking the the import `*` ... but its interesting that practically __every__ pytk tutorial out there does this ...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if they're doing it to avoid all those `tk.Bla` things to make things more readable, but having ~190 names in your module namespace doesn't help much :S

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make each row in the grid not be forced to lineup with the row above it?

Comment: Hm, that's not how `grid` works... As I said, you can use more columns and columnspans or switch the geometry manager completely, i.e. `pack`. I don't know how to do that with this, though.